# Echo information in quotes on a line containing a specific string?

Tags: batch-file

If I had a text file that was a list of things in the following format:

```
Thing1   "Description of Thing1"
Thing2   "Description of Thing2"
etc.
```

How would I use a batch file to echo only the information contained in the quotes for any given thing?

Edit: Per the answer, I've tried the following:

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (G:\Games\Console\Emulators\MAME\listfull.txt) do if "%%a"=="%%~nf" set gamename=%%~b
    echo !gamename!
    if !count!==1 echo|set /P=", "!gamename!": [#name: "%%~nf", #path: "%%~dpf"]" >> "G:\Games\Console\Utilities\Lists\MAME_%%d.txt"
```

It almost totally works; if the description contains an &, symbol, however, "echo !gamename!" works while the next line doesn't and spits out that "&' isn't a command. (I have to use the echo|set to produce lines that don't have a carriage return.)

Edit2: The only solution I've found is to add an ^ before every & in whatever text file I'm reading the descriptions from. Not an ideal workaround, but...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "search=Thing2"
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (textfile.txt) do if "%%a"=="%search%" echo %%~b
```

If all this script does is outputs the information for any given `thing`, then you could change search to `%~1` and just input the value when calling the script.

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (textfile.txt) do if "%%a"=="%~1" echo %%~b
```

Comment: Works great. Much appreciated.

Comment: I notice that I'm running into issues if the description contains any & symbols.

Comment: Note the added quotes around the search term, which will allow `&` etc.

Comment: Beat me to it. Cheers, foxi.

Comment: My problem comes from the fact that I'm using
'echo|set /p='
in order to list a bunch of information without carriage returns. I've tried adding double quotes to various things, but it never works out. I'm trying to figure out a way to post the code here but thee character limit is hindering me.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the code. If you can help, I'm much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in (file.txt) do echo(%%~b
```

Comment: Though I've seen it used often, I've never understood the usage of the open bracket with an echo command. What is the purpose of using it over a space or full stop?

Comment: @unclemeat If the variable is empty or has only spaces and/or tabs you get the unwanted `ECHO is OFF.` message. The reason to avoid the full stop is more difficult, it can cause bugs. There are more discussions at `dostips.com`.

Comment: I might have been clearer -- by "any given thing" I meant "any specific thing", rather than every one of them. The solution above does what I need, but thanks!